# Translate3d doesn't move embedded element in Safari (Windows only)

Tags: css, safari, transform, embed, translate3d

I'm trying to move an embedded element with the CSS3's transform: translate3d() method. It works perfectly in every browser, except for Safari, which **doesn't seem to move the video/audio itself** but manages to move the embedded element.

Here's the [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c5p63/5/).

I've moved a container div to the right with translate3d(). I've also set a border for the div and the embedded element/object.

**HTML**

```
<div class="audio">
    <object height="50" width="100"
     data="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3"></object>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.audio{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(300px,0,0);
}
```

Is this an unfixable bug or does anyone have a fix?

EDIT:

**Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 8.1**

[image: Safari 5.1.7 on Windows]

Comment: What version of Safari are you running? As far as I can tell, your fiddle is functioning exactly the same in both Safari 7.0.1 and Chrome 32.0 (on Mac OS X 10.9.1)

Comment: I've just tested it on BrowserStack (don't know why I didn't think of that earlier) but it appears to be a Windows only problem. Safari on Mac seems to be just fine. I've added a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Safari for windows is no longer updated, so it is irrelevant (Like testing on firefox 3, or chrome 20)... If you need to support it, provide support with degradation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd be weighing the cost of finding a fix versus the actual users you'd affect. I don't think there are enough users to justify trying to find a fix, especially because the description of the problem sounds like it may be a Safari 5 bug.

Safari 5.7 doesn't even show up on [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) for `transforms3d`

And [Safari 5 is only 0.2% of interet users in April](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_safari.asp) and that stat doesn't even show the split between Windows and other operating systems, so it could be even less.

I tried to find a version of Safari 5 to run in Virtual Box: Windows 8.1, but I couldn't even find it...

Comment: Yeah, it's been a while. I've since moved on and haven't fixed it. I'll just mark your answer as correct.